# synchronous fetch to replace synchronous ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch, synchronous

I understand that making synchronous calls are not recommended, but I have to make a synchronous call in ajax, since I am dealing with a device which requires user action before I get the response from it. My ajax() code below has been working great until now. I am getting the warning that "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated". 
Synchronous call returns the response (from the device) and I pass it to my second call and output gets generated:

```js
<script>  
var result = $.ajax({
    url: 'url',
 async: false,
 type: "GET"
}).responseText;

$(document).ready(function() {   
    $.post("https://example.com/doit.php", {
        response: result,account: <?php echo $account ?>,dn:<?php echo $dn ?>, mode:<?php echo $dest ?>},function(data){document.write(data);});
    });
</script>
```

How can I change the synchronous call to keep this working.

Comment: `but I have to make a synchronous call in ajax` - no you don't. You never do. Show a modal spinner that prevents further UI interaction, do anything else, but don't make a synchronous request. Ever.

Comment: Your code is working. You get a *warning* that synchronous is deprecated. You ask us how to make a synchronous request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $.ajax({
          url: 'url',
          type: "GET",
          success: function(r){
             var result = r.responseText;
             $.post("https://example.com/doit.php",{response: result,account: <?php echo $account ?>,dn:<?php echo $dn ?>, mode:<?php echo $dest ?>},function(data){document.write(data);});
          }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Matt. Your answer helped me to solve the problem. I added an ajax-loader image to appear on beforeSend and disappear at complete.

Answer (score 0):

Do your post request in the success callback of your get:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'url',
    type: "GET"
})
    .then(function(responseText) {
        return $.post(...)
    })
    .then(function(postResponse) {
        ..do whatever
    })
```